# Cannot start Realtek 8723 bluetooth in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, realtek

I have a notebook HP 14-bp006ur with Realtek wifi/bluetooth combo. I have started wifi on it. However, I cannot start bluetooth. There is some info I can provide with.

```
$ uname -a
Linux Tatooin 5.3.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 01:33:18 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   14.638417] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   14.638471] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.638479] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.638483] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.638490] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   14.998135] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[   14.999129] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=2
[   14.999134] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[   15.235028] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[   15.245728] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 33266
[   17.408107] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[   25.472227] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: download fw command failed (-110)
[   33.592982] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   33.592986] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   33.592995] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[14899.254455] Modules linked in: ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bpfilter ccm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc rtl8723de(OE) btcoexist(OE) phydm_mod(OE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi rtl8723_common(OE) rtl_pci(OE) rtlwifi(OE) mac80211 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_powerclamp ledtrig_audio coretemp i915 cfg80211 libarc4 snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec kvm snd_hda_core irqbypass snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event punit_atom_debug snd_rawmidi drm_kms_helper snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer drm snd crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul mei_hdcp i2c_algo_bit ghash_clmulni_intel fb_sys_fops mei_txe soundcore syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt mei intel_rapl_msr aesni_intel processor_thermal_device intel_rapl_common intel_xhci_usb_role_switch intel_soc_dts_iosf roles aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper intel_cstate joydev input_leds int3403_thermal
[30105.606151] Modules linked in: nls_iso8859_1 uas usb_storage ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bpfilter ccm bnep uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc rtl8723de(OE) btcoexist(OE) phydm_mod(OE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi rtl8723_common(OE) rtl_pci(OE) rtlwifi(OE) mac80211 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_powerclamp ledtrig_audio coretemp i915 cfg80211 libarc4 snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec kvm snd_hda_core irqbypass snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event punit_atom_debug snd_rawmidi drm_kms_helper snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer drm snd crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul mei_hdcp i2c_algo_bit ghash_clmulni_intel fb_sys_fops mei_txe soundcore syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt mei intel_rapl_msr aesni_intel processor_thermal_device intel_rapl_common intel_xhci_usb_role_switch intel_soc_dts_iosf roles aes_x86_64 crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper intel_cstate joydev
[33744.081319] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[33744.082340] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=2
[33744.082345] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[33744.082408] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[33744.082551] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 33266
[33746.224942] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[33754.289096] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: download fw command failed (-110)
[33783.369462] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[33783.371114] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=2
[33783.371123] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[33783.371468] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[33783.371661] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 33266
[33785.598298] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[33793.714445] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: download fw command failed (-110)

$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
        DOWN
        RX bytes:917 acl:0 sco:0 events:130 errors:0
        TX bytes:33030 acl:0 sco:0 commands:131 errors:0
        Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
        Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1
        Link policy:
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT

$ hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Cannot assign requested address (99)

$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-01-05 02:17:51 MSK; 58min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 19811 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4545)
   Memory: 616.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─19811 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 05 02:17:50 Tatooin systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Succeeded.
Jan 05 02:17:50 Tatooin systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Jan 05 02:17:50 Tatooin systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jan 05 02:17:51 Tatooin bluetoothd[19811]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Jan 05 02:17:51 Tatooin systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 05 02:17:51 Tatooin bluetoothd[19811]: Starting SDP server
Jan 05 02:17:51 Tatooin bluetoothd[19811]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Jan 05 02:17:51 Tatooin bluetoothd[19811]: No Bluetooth address for index 0

$ lsusb; rfkill list
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05c8:0233 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

$ usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=b009 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n WLAN Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb

$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# devices
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# exit

$ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             581632  14 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
```

How to revive my bluetooth module?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue for the past week or so on 18.04.3 kern 4.17 rc7